# Roman Calculator troubles in Java. StringIndexOutOfBounds in my for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, exception, calculator

I'm creating a Roman Numeral calculator for a Java course I'm taking. The following method is supposed to take a Roman Numeral value and convert it to an integer. I keep getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error when it runs and I don't quite understand where my error lies. Any help would be appreciated!

I have put the Roman Numerals and the corresponding Arabic Numerals into their own arrays, as noted here:

```
private String[] romanArr = {"M", "D", "C", "X", "L", "V", "I"};

 private int[] arabicArr = {1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1};
```

Here is my method for the conversion:

```
int convert_from_Roman(String value)
 {  
     value.trim();
     int convertedValue = 0;


     for (int i = 0; i <= value.length(); i++)
     {   
        char romanVal = value.charAt(i);

        for(String romanNumeral : romanArr)
         {
             if (romanNumeral.equals(romanVal))
             {
                 convertedValue += arabicArr[romanNumeral.indexOf(i)];
             }
             else 
                 continue;
         } 
     } 

     return convertedValue;

     }
```

Lastly, here is my code in main in which I create the variable *numeral* and give it a Roman Numeral String to pass to the method *convert_from_Roman* using an object of the *RomanCalculator* class and print the result.:

```
RomanCalculator mc = new RomanCalculator();
 String numeral = "I";
 System.out.println(mc.convert_from_Roman(numeral) );
```

Comment: If indices start at 0, and the length is 5, what's the last valid index? Also, what does the trim() method do? And, given that you get an exception, with an error message and a location and a stack trace, why don't you read it to find out what and where the problem is?

Comment: Try that: for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)

Comment: Comparison of a String with char: romanNumeral.equals(romanVal)

Comment: Here's an idea that you could make work.  Store the Roman numerals and their `Integer` equivalent in a `HashMap<String,Integer>`, or better still, a `HashMap<Character,Integer>`.  That way, the `HashMap` code will do all the hard work of matching the `Character` and finding the matching `Integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get and out of bound exception in two places.

The first place is in `value.charAt(i)` since you're exceeding the index by 1 using `<=` instead `<`. Here is where you get the exception `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The second place is in `arabicArr[romanNumeral.indexOf(i)]`, the variable *i* is the current index of the input string, and it is taken as a char by the function `indexOf()`, this function returns -1 when the char is not found, and given that i will be 0, 1, 2..., it will return -1 the first time when looking for the ascii code with value 0 throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also a string - char comparison will return always `false`.

```java
int convert_from_Roman(String value) {  
    value.trim(); // result of trim is ignored
    int convertedValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= value.length(); i++) { // your exceeding the index by 1
        char romanVal = value.charAt(i);
        for(String romanNumeral : romanArr) {
            if (romanNumeral.equals(romanVal)) { // string - char comparison
                 convertedValue += arabicArr[romanNumeral.indexOf(i)]; // wrong index
            }
            else 
                continue;
        } 
    } 
    return convertedValue;
}
```

Fixed convert from roman method.

```java
int convert_from_Roman(String value) {  
    String trimmed = value.trim(); // using the result of trim
    int convertedValue = 0;
    for (int digit = 0; digit < trimmed.length(); digit++) { // < instead <=
        char romanVal = trimmed.charAt(digit);
        for(int roman = 0; roman < romanArr.length; roman++) {
            if (romanArr[roman].equals(String.valueOf(romanVal))) // char char comparison
                convertedValue += arabicArr[roman]; // fixed index
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
    return convertedValue;
}
```